# Scroll to new tab when drawer item selected

Tags: java, android, drawer

So I have created custom ViewPager, PagerAdapter and drawer. Now I want to call Tab which is in position of clicked drawer item. As it is all custom cannot Use transaction. I'm not new to java so no need to rewrite program just write what to do.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){
        selectDrawerItem(position);
        /*  scroll code here*/
    }

    private void selectDrawerItem(int position) {
        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would work, but scrolls so fast. in your onItemClick method.

```
viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position,true);
```

Comment: Tried it working, but scroll not smooth, anyway, Thank you.